# pointers to function error

Tags: c, function, pointers

hello guys i'm kinda new in here and in c also i've been practising pointers to functions and i've come up with this code :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef int (*fptr)(int,int);
void swapp(int*,int*);
int sub(int ,int );
int add(int ,int );
int operation(fptr,int,int);
int main()
{
    int n=10,n1=25;
    printf("%d+%d=%d",n,n1,compute(add,n,n1));
    printf("\n%d-%d=%d",(n>n1)?n:n1,(n<n1)?n:n1,compute(sub,n,n1));


    return 0;
}
void swapp(int *a,int *b){
    int temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}
int add(int a,int b){
    return a+b;
}
int sub(int a,int b){
    if(a<b)
    swapp(a,b);
    return a-b;
}
int compute(fptr operation ,int a,int b){

    return operation(a,b);
}
```

when compiled i get "Segmentation Fault(core duped) can anyone help me debug this? and thx i just can't see anything wrong with the code

Comment: Are you saying that the compiler crashed( I doubt that)?  Or, you are getting this error when you RUN your program?

Comment: error at run time, it's solved the error was the use of swapp in the sub function it's solved now thx guys :)

Comment: Turn on warnings in your compiler ... that would have caught this. And learn how to use your debugger, don't ask SO for help debugging individual programs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

need prototype

```
int compute(fptr operation ,int a,int b);
```

and

```
swapp(a,b);
```

to

```
swapp(&a,&b);
```

Comment: If this answer helped you then you would like to accept it. Read [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more detail.

Comment: @haccks I appreciate your kindness